# Axios post request returns undefined for req.query

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am trying to pass data using axios.post method to the express server backend but it gives undefined.

Here's the frontend code:

```
const login = async (codeParam) => {
  if (codeParam.code.length > 1) {
    try {
      console.log("login with", codeParam) //returns the right value {code: 'value'}
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:8000/getAccessToken",
        codeParam
      )

      if (response.data) {
        console.log("access token:", response.data.access_token)
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data.access_token))
        localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", true)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the backend route:

```
app.post("/getAccessToken", (req, res) => {
  console.log("code", req.query.code) //returns undefined
  axios
    .post("https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token", {
      client_id: process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_SECRET,
      code: req.query.code,
      redirect_uri: process.env.REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI,
    })
    .then((result) => {
      console.log("access token backend", result.data)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("error:", err)
    })
})
```

I am trying to pass the "codeParam" object to the backend route but it's giving undefined. Here's what I get on the console:

```
code undefined
access token backend error=bad_verification_code&error_description=The+code+passed+is+incorrect+or+expired.&error_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.github.com%2Fapps%2Fmanaging-oauth-apps%2Ftroubleshooting-oauth-app-access-token-request-errors%2F%23bad-verification-code
```

The problem is:

```
req.query.code
```

It should return something or maybe I am doing it wrong?

Comment: You don't send any `query`. You send a `body`

Comment: Wow! can't believe that was the problem. Been banging my head all day. Thank you!